# Dask and numpy - slow conversion between numpy array and dask array

Tags: python, numpy, dask, dask-distributed

I need to save a dask array from a big numpy array. Below there is a minimum working example that’s show the process. Note that `a` is created with `numpy.random` only for this mwe, unfortunately I can not create the array with dask.

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
from dask.distributed import Client

a = numpy.random.randint(0,2,size=4000000*8000).reshape((4000000,8000))
# here the conversion and saving
client = Client(n_workers=90, threads_per_worker=20, processes=True)
dask_array = da.from_array( a, chunks = 100000)
da.to_npy_stack(‘my-folder/’, dask_array)
client.close()
```

The problem that I am facing is that `a` in memory takes around 100GB, however when running the dask part the memory used starts going up until it almost full the available ram, that is more than 300GB. Then it does some computing and I got a memory error after some time (like 10 minutes). I need the array saved by dask as I have another pipeline (which cannot be connected directly to this pipeline) that’s using dask arrays and to read a dask array from memory the `info` file is required (if there is any other method to dump the array and create the `info` file I am open to try it).

Any suggestions on how to speed up and solve this task?

Comment: Instead of creating the array with numpy, can you create with dask ?
> arr = da.random.randint(0,2,size=4000000*8000).reshape((4000000,8000))

Comment: No, unfortunately I can not create the array with dask. @quasiben

Comment: how are you reading in the data ?

Comment: Data are coming from torch. But that’s out of scope for this question. I can also accept that it is not possible to use dask in this way, I am just looking for answers. Thank you @quasiben

Comment: any techniques in https://examples.dask.org/machine-learning/torch-prediction.html useful for you ?

Comment: Thank you @quasiben, I got your point, unfortunately I cannot modify the before code (that is why I am saying it is out of scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a single machine then I recommend using the standard threaded scheduler rather than the `dask.distributed.Client`.  You will keep all of the data in the same process this way, and remove the need to make copies of your large Numpy array.

Comment: I will try it. In the meantime let me ask why dask developers suggest to always use the distributed scheduler even on a single machine @MRocklin

Comment: I personally do not suggest that you always use the distributed scheduler, just that it's usually a robustly good choice.  There is no solution that is always the best choice in all situations.

Answer (score 1):

Creating all of your data in the main process and then uploading it to the worker processes is a bad idea! You should always endeavour to load/create the data directly in the workers, which will a) avoid repeating work and copying data and b) keep the data lazy, only materialising it into memory at need:

In this case, this might look like

```
arr = da.random.randint(0, 2, size=4000000*8000, chunks=100000).reshape((4000000,8000))
```

Comment: (I wasn't sure about the chunks, whether you wanted that many original pieces or output pieces)

Comment: Thanks @mdurant, however as I commented also in the main question body I can not directly create the array with dask. The code is just an example for running it. The data are coming from another pipeline.